# Magento - Completed and Cancelled order state 1 hour behind

Tags: php, magento

I am in the process of creating an order history table that logs all order and order line changes whenever the order state or status is changed. 
I obviously have a date stamp when the order is saved too.

The problem I'm having is, when the order is created (new state) it outputs the correct time. 
As soon as I ship the item (complete state) the time stamp is an hour behind.

I'm simply doing the following

```
$data['order_save_time'] = self::_getDate(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your server time zone, take a look @ [Magento date time](http://magentocookbook.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/magento-date-time/) or [Playing with Dates in Magento](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/playing-with-dates-in-magento/).

In your self::_getDate() you should be doing

```
$currentTimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()); //Magento's timestamp function makes a usage of timezone and converts it to timestamp
echo $date = date('Y-m-d', $currentTimestamp); //The value may differ than above because of the timezone settings.
```

or using

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
```